# Show active document name in the title of Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I want to show the active document name in Visual Studio's window title. How is this possible?

Eg. If I have Web.config active in the workspace. Then the window title would be:

`web.config` - (solutionname) - Visual Studio 2008 or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a macros. Some example how to do this you [can find here](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/32)

Comment: The mentioned macro shows a full path of the document. To show just document name followed by a solution name, replace: ideTitle = GotFocus.Document.FullName with

Comment: ideTitle = GotFocus.Document.Name
Try
ideTitle &= " - (" & IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(DTE.Solution.FullName) & ")"
Catch ex As Exception
End Try